# Find Maximum of this Function

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

I'm sure this is a simple solution, but I can't find a proper explanation online.

I'm currently reading Algorithmic Game Theory, and at one point the author states that given the function

> $x(1-t-x)$, the highest value $x$ can be is $ \frac{(1-t)}{2} $.

I can see this is true from just plugging in values of $t$ and finding the critical points. For example $x(1-0.5-x)$, $x$ has a value of $.25$

Can someone please explain to me how the author deduced $\frac{(1-t)}{2}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Second derivative test. The first derivative evaluates to 0 when $x=\frac{1-t}{2}$ and the second derivative is negative

Comment: You probably want to find that value of $x$ that yields the highest value of $x(1-t-x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done without [calculus](/questions/tagged/calculus).  Just completing the square in [algebra-precalculus](/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) will do.

\begin{align}
x(1-t-x) &= -(x^2 - (1-t)x) \\
&= -\left(x^2-2\cdot\left(\frac{1-t}{2}\right) x + \left(\frac{1-t}{2}\right)^2\right) + \left(\frac{1-t}{2}\right)^2 \\
&= \underbrace{-\left((x-\frac{1-t}{2}\right)^2}_{\le 0} + \left(\frac{1-t}{2}\right)^2
\end{align}

Therefore, $x = \dfrac{1-t}{2}$ maximizes $x(1-t-x)$.

Answer (score 0):

write your term in the form
$$-\left(x^2-2\frac{1-t}{2}x+\left(\frac{1-t}{2}\right)^2\right)+\left(\frac{1-t}{2}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Expand: 
$$x(1-t-x)=-x^2+(1-t)x.$$
Note that the inverted parabola attains max at its vertex:
$$x_0=-\frac{b}{2a}=-\frac{1-t}{-2}=\frac{1-t}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple geometric argument:

The graph of $p(x) = x(1-t-x)$ is a parabola open downwards which intersects the $x$-axis at $x=0$ and $x= 1-t$.

So, the maximum is attained at the vertex which is because of the symmetry of the parabola exactly in the middle between the two zeros:

$$x_{max} = \frac{0+1-t}{2}= \frac{1-t}{2} \rightarrow y_{max} = \frac{1-t}{2}(1-t - \frac{1-t}{2}) = \left( \frac{1-t}{2} \right)^2$$

Comment: Is here a maths hater who distributes down votes randomly?
would be nice to know why this anwer deserves a down vote.

Comment: +1 for simple answer. I wonder for the OP accepted the relatively difficult answer.